Brownian bridge kernel method (BBKM) in adehabitatHR: 'subscript out of bounds' error for home range getverticeshr ()
I have a dataframe with 5-minutes relocation data recorded for several days and for 500+ cows. I created a loop to calculate the daily explored area (home range) of each cow using the minimum convex polygon (MCP) and the Brownian Bridge Kernel Method (BBKM). The loop is applied to each cow identified through a cm_id and the calculated areas are stack-stored in a csv file using the fwrite function.
While the loop works well with some cm_ids, it does not with others. The following error pops up and the loop stops:
Error in re[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Here there is a subsample of the data with 5 cows, two where the script works well (cm_id: 280 and 458) and three with troubles.
text
Below the script I wrote and used:
library("adehabitatHR")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")
setwd('K:Downloads')

load(file = 'test_dataframe.Rdata')
ID_list <- data.frame(c(280, 458, 281, 457, 460))
colnames(ID_list) <- "cow_mob"

system.time( #Timing the execution
  for (iRow in 1:nrow(ID_list))
     {
   
    # iRow <- 1 #manually applying the script to cm_id 280
    print(iRow)
    cow_mob        <- ID_list[iRow,] #select once at a time, each cow_mob ID from the list of IDs
    print(paste0('cm_ID'," ",cow_mob))
    
    datasetHR_onecow <- datasetHR  #start the loop with all clean data
    datasetHR_onecow <- datasetHR_onecow %>% filter(cm_id == cow_mob) #apply filter to each individual cow_mob
    #Manual filter to specific dates and timestamp
    # datasetHR_onecow <- subset(datasetHR_onecow, timestamp >= ymd_hms("2019-07-03 00:00:00" , tz="NZ") &
    #                              timestamp <= ymd_hms("2019-08-20 23:59:59" , tz="NZ"))
    
    # # #Minimum Convex Polygon  
    dataset_trajectory <- data.frame( paste0(datasetHR_onecow$cm_id, "_", datasetHR_onecow$date))
    colnames(dataset_trajectory) = c('cm_day_id')
    utm_coor <- datasetHR_onecow %>% dplyr::select(X_Easting, Y_Northing) #creates dataframe with coordinates in UTM
    colnames(utm_coor) = c("x", "y")
    coordinates(dataset_trajectory) <- utm_coor  #add coordinates and convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame
    proj4string(dataset_trajectory) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2193") #assigns the UTM Coordinates Reference System
    # #plot(dataset_trajectory)
    
    poligon95 <- mcp(dataset_trajectory, percent = 95) #calculates area per day using MCP adehabitatHR at 95%
    poligon50 <- mcp(dataset_trajectory, percent = 50) #calculates area per day using MCP adehabitatHR at 50%

    # #Brownian bridge kernel method (BBKM)
    dataset_trajectory <-data.frame(dataset_trajectory)
    dataset_trajectory$timestamp <- datasetHR_onecow$timestamp
    
    trajectory.lt <- as.ltraj(xy =dataset_trajectory[,c( "x", "y")], date = dataset_trajectory$timestamp,
                              id =dataset_trajectory$cm_day_id)
    #plot(trajectory.lt)
    
    tata <- kernelbb(trajectory.lt, sig1 = 0.9178178, sig2 = 7, grid = 50)
    
    hr_bbkm95 <- getverticeshr(tata, 95) #Calculates area per day using BBKM adehabitatHR at 95%
    hr_bbkm95 <- as.data.frame(hr_bbkm95)
    
    HRcow_mob <- data.frame(cbind(poligon95$id, poligon95$area, poligon50$area, hr_bbkm95$area)) #creates dataframe with id and area
    colnames(HRcow_mob) = c('id', 'hr_MCP95', 'hr_MCP50', 'hr_bbkm95')
    #HRcow_mob
    
    #Creates csv file where MCP & BBKM home ranges for each cow_mob and day are appended
    fwrite(HRcow_mob, "hr_day_mcp_bbkm_test.csv" , append =TRUE, sep = ",", dateTimeAs = "write.csv")
    gc()
  }
)

The script will run through all cm_ids automatically; alternatively, it can be applied to any choosen individual cm_id by commenting:
for (iRow in 1:nrow(ID_list))
     {

and instead uncommenting the line:
# iRow <- 1 #manually applying the script to cm_id 280

which chooses the first cm_id or the one desired (e.g., 2, 3, 4 or 5).
I also used a filter to include/exclude specific days whithin a cm_id in case the problem was in a specific day.
datasetHR_onecow <- subset(datasetHR_onecow, timestamp >= ymd_hms("2019-07-03 00:00:00" , tz="NZ") &
                                 timestamp <= ymd_hms("2019-08-20 23:59:59" , tz="NZ"))

This has been partially useful because of, for a cm_id causing the error, I could apply the script to, let me say, half of the days of a cm_id and it will run well. Then, I applied the script to the other half of the days of the same cm_id and again it will run properly. However, when the script is applied to all days of that cm_id, the error will show up.
I also tested commenting the BBKM part and running the script with the MCP home range part only, and the script ran properly for all cm_ids. Therefore, the problem is definitively within the BBKM and not with MCP or another part of the script. Actually, the error appears when runing the getverticeshr() function.
The expected results would look like the following, but for all 5 cm_ids:

Any ideas what could be causing this problem? Thanks!
This issue seems to be related to this other question (text), but not complete answer was given.
